# Get last date for x day of a given month in Javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime, calendar

I've been trying to figure out how to get the date of the last x day of a month in JavaScript without using a loop. I'm sure its to do with using the modulus operator but I cant quite get the formula right :-(

So for example the date for the last Monday in this month (06/2013) would be the 24th.

Can anyone shed some light on this? It's driving me nuts!

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**

I think I have it working now thanks to having a look inside how `date.js` do it, I was close with what I had though!

```
function getLastDay(year, month, dayOfWeek)
{
    var d = new Date(year, month, 0);
    var diff = (dayOfWeek - d.getDay() + 7 * -1) % 7;

    return new Date(year, month-1, d.getDate() + diff);
}

// Last Monday in for January 2013
getLastDay(2013, 1, 1); // Mon Jan 28 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)
```

Comment: Have you got some code you've been working on? I've had a look at this and have managed to achieve this functionality with a while loop but can't think of a way of achieving what you're after

Comment: The code I have is quite simple so far. It just finds the last date of this month then attempts to work the difference out to the day of the week given and then subtract it from the date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, misread your question at first. Editing my response.

If you're willing to use a library, try [date.js.](http://www.datejs.com/)

You can use the [moveToNthOccurence](https://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/APIDocumentation#moveToNthOccurrence) with -1 to get the last occurence of a day in the month.

So:

```
Date.today().moveToNthOccurrence(1, -1)
```

should give you the last Monday of this month.